# CSS for the new <kbd> style

Tags: support, css

The new `<kbd>` CSS is not loading for some users. So, for those who just can't wait, use your favorite CSS browser extension/feature to implement it yourself!

```
kbd
{
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
    color:#333;
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:1.4;
    margin:0 .1em;
    padding:.1em .6em;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

### Credit: [@jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin)

Comment: AWESOME!! Me likey!

Answer (score 12):

[image: kbd]

Comment: +1 for the time spent creating this layout.

Answer (score 12):

This post is used for testing purposes; if you somehow don't have the new CSS (after doing a cache refresh like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) you can use an extension like [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) for Chrome and copy iglvzx's CSS into it.

I'm unaware of such add-on for Firefox, so they might need to write [an user style sheet](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/ht/htcssuserfirefo.htm) or write a GM user script to insert a `<style>` tag. For Internet Explorer there is [Trixie](http://www.bhelpuri.net/Trixie/) for running GM user scripts. Note that this should only be used as a temporary fix *if you [just can't wait](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywjX6AF6oVc)*...

A keyboard, as can be seen in iglvzx's post, but with `<kbd>` tags:

<kbd>`</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>Bkspc</kbd>

<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>

<kbd>Caps</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>

And now for some bug tests:

<kbd>***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************</kbd>

However, image bugs seems to have been fixed:

<kbd>[image]</kbd><kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image][image]</kbd>

Comment: You broke the Internet again!

Comment: @iglvzx: Seems the images bug has been resolved, the other two bugs are still there. Breaking it another time: `````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````` And well, the quote bug is also still there but irrelevant to post it here... :)

Comment: How do you think they should be fixed? See my quick CSS fix on my other answer.

Comment: My god, how did I miss that Lion King reference!?

Comment: See my response to your other answer.

Answer (score 2):

In response to @Tom's bugs, the following CSS is a basic fix:

```
kbd
{
  max-width: 624px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

---

### Before:

[image: before]

### After:

[image: after]

Comment: Yeah, similar fixes were already suggested on Meta.SO which also fix the quote bug; but I've yet to see one for the comment bug. In any case, introducing automatic wrapping / scrolling in case of bugs isn't a bad idea.

Comment: Ha! I've fixed the comment bug. I will post on Meta.SO :)